# Using anova() on multivariable quantile regression model with natural splines generates error

Tags: r, anova, spline, quantile-regression, quantreg

I created a multivariable quantile regression model:

```
model <- rq(y ~ x1 + x2+ x3... + ns(high_value_x,df=5), tau = seq(0.1, 0.9, by = 0.1), data = df,  method='fn')
```

The `high_value_x` represent a continuous, numerical variable with very high values (median ~35,000) compared to other variables (categorical 0 to 1, or continuous between -10 to 300).
I have got an error:

```
> anova(model)
Error in solve.default(D %*% W %*% t(D), D %*% coef) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 3.89884e-19
```

I found that to obtain results of `anova()` on my model I need to:

- drop entirely variable `high_value_x`
- create a new variable by diving `high_value_x` by at least `100` (but without using natural splines for transformation!)
  (the last solution was inspired by: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76488/error-system-is-computationally-singular-when-running-a-glm)

Initially, I used natural splines to fit nonlinear association between `y` and `high_value_x`.

**a) How natural splines transformation effects the `anova()` that I cannot obtain the anova statics?
b) Is it rationale to transform `high_value_x` by dividing by at least 100 if it has a nonlinear association with dependent variable, and `ns()` with `df = 5` improve fitting in univariate model?
c) Is any other solution for the error?**

Comment: (1) a [mcve] would be very helpful.  (2) in general scaling variables has no effect on the overall inference/conclusions from the model (you can always rescale parameter values etc. after fitting), so if it helps you overcome computational problems you should just do it -- there *may* be other ways to solve the problem, but scaling is usually easiest.